# Why MODI doesn't let me delete the processed file?

Tags: c#, file, ocr, delete-file, modi

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        OCR.recognize("test1.tif");
        System.IO.File.Delete("test1.tif"); // <--- Problem on this line
}

....

public static string recognize(string filepath, MODI.MiLANGUAGES language =
MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_RUSSIAN)
{
        if (!File.Exists(filepath)) return "error 1: File does not exist";
        MODI.Document doc = new MODI.Document();
        doc.Create(filepath);

        doc.OCR(language, true, true);
        MODI.Image image = (MODI.Image)doc.Images[0];

        string result="";
        foreach (MODI.Word worditems in image.Layout.Words)
        {
            result += worditems.Text + ' ';

        // Processed image is ALWAYS a question
            if (worditems.Text[worditems.Text.Length - 1] == '?') break;
        }


        doc.Close();

        return result;

}
```

Problem is: File is used by another process.

How do I delete it after OCR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone [posted a solution](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.interop/browse_thread/thread/1a5a2b32c8b33a11/?pli=1) for this:

```
public void Dispose()  
{   
        doc.Close(false); 
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc);
        doc = null; 
        GC.Collect();
}
```

Maybe it works for your case, too.

Comment: You can still use Process Monitor from SysInternals to see which process actually accesses the file. Maybe it is something different than you currently think is it. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: No, its that application. quiz.vshost.exe where quiz is my app.

Comment: This fixed it:
            
            image = null;
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();